# SCrollView Updates

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scrollview

I am using this method:

```
  - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

And I get updates of my scroll view offset. The problem is that my scroll view updates itself to often. Is there a way to reduce the update intervals?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that ? It's totally okey that you get it every single time, when scroll view didScroll

Comment: No, but you can fitler it yourself. Keep time of the last value you used and compare your actual time when you get new values...

Comment: Use `NSTimer` to accumulate messages, there are tons of examples doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a draft of using a timer to achieve this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (!_delayTimer) {
        _delayTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.2
                               target:self selector:@selector(delayed)
                               userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
}

- (void)delayed {
    _delayTimer = nil;
    [self doSomething:_scrollView.contentOffset];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to filter the results the way you want them.  I do the same in a webView to change the animation frequency from 60 to 30 hertz.  In my example we use the scrollviewDidScroll results every .03 seconds.  That can be modified to any amount you want.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
    static NSDate *date;
    if(!date)
        date = [NSDate date];

    //Check if we have gone long enough since the last desired update
    if([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:date] > .03)
    {
        //Enough time has passed, do your updates here
        date = [NSDate date];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, you will miss some events, and will not guarantee your controller state is at last scroll value. i.e. if the views scrolls during that 0.03s you just lose data. Even if .03 is not that much, depending on what he wants to do, it can matter

Comment: @VincentG That is true.  But he said he was getting too many events.  This is a way to reduce the amount of events that he "sees".  The events will still happen, but he will only "see" a small alottment of them (which is what he asked for).  This is pretty much the same as your answer, but less convoluted.